# sql 2008 remove duplicates from inner join

Tags: sql-server-2008, duplicates, inner-join

Using SQL 2008 R2.  I am trying to find Employees that are Active, but were previously employees in one of our other companies. The following code works; however, I noticed that if the Employee has worked for more than two companies, I get duplicates.  Is there another way that I need to write this so that I do not get duplicates?  I have tried using the Group By and case with when exist and nothing seems to work.

SAMPLE DATA

```css
╔═════════════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ SSN         ║ PRCo ║ Employee ║ FullName ║ HireDate ║ ActiveYN ║
╠═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 123-45-6789 ║ 17   ║ 456789   ║ John Doe ║ 05/27/13 ║ Y        ║
╠═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 123-45-6789 ║ 23   ║ 456789   ║ John Doe ║ 08/22/11 ║ N        ║
╠═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 123-45-6789 ║ 1    ║ 456789   ║ John Doe ║ 12/03/07 ║ N        ║
╠═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 999-99-9999 ║ 17   ║ 999999   ║ Jane Doe ║ 05/27/13 ║ Y        ║
╠═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 999-99-9999 ║ 23   ║ 999999   ║ Jane Doe ║ 01/26/09 ║ N        ║
╚═════════════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Using the following code

```
select distinct p1.SSN, p1.PRCo, p1.Employee, n.FullName, p1.HireDate, p1.ActiveYN, 
    case when p1.ActiveYN = 'Y' then 'Y'
         when p2.ActiveYN = 'Y' then 'Y' 
         else 'N' end as AnyActiveCo

from PREH as p1
     inner join PREH as p2 on p1.SSN=p2.SSN
     left outer join PREHFullName as n on p1.PRCo=n.PRCo and p1.Employee=n.Employee

where p1.PRCo<>p2.PRCo
```

RESULTS; Row 3 & 5 are duplicates and do not have the desired AnyActiveCo result for an employee that was in 3 different companies; however employees with just 2 companies show fine.

```css
╔═════╦═════════════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ Row ║ SSN         ║ PRCo ║ Employee ║ FullName ║ HireDate ║ ActiveYN ║ AnyActiveCo ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1   ║ 123-45-6789 ║ 17   ║ 456789   ║ John Doe ║ 05/27/13 ║ Y        ║ Y           ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2   ║ 123-45-6789 ║ 23   ║ 456789   ║ John Doe ║ 08/22/11 ║ N        ║ Y           ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 3   ║ 123-45-6789 ║ 23   ║ 456789   ║ John Doe ║ 08/22/11 ║ N        ║ N           ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 4   ║ 123-45-6789 ║ 1    ║ 456789   ║ John Doe ║ 12/03/07 ║ N        ║ Y           ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 5   ║ 123-45-6789 ║ 1    ║ 456789   ║ John Doe ║ 12/03/07 ║ N        ║ N           ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 6   ║ 999-99-9999 ║ 17   ║ 999999   ║ Jane Doe ║ 05/27/13 ║ Y        ║ Y           ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 7   ║ 999-99-9999 ║ 23   ║ 999999   ║ Jane Doe ║ 01/26/09 ║ N        ║ Y           ║
╚═════╩═════════════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: `distinct` applies to the entire row. it's not a "per-field" distinct. `select distinct a,b,c` is (somewhat, but not really) the same as having done `select a,b,c ... group by a,b,c`

Comment: We have no idea, as we do not know your tables structures and what is stored in each of the columns. But apparently if `HireDate` are unique to each of the companies, you would not get rid of the duplicates with a mere `distinct`.

Comment: better sample and result data added